# How to visualize Weierstrass M test?

Tags: real-analysis

Weierstrass $M$ test states that ,
If {${f_n}$} is a sequence of functions on $D$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M_n$ for every $x$ in $D$ for some $M_n$.If $M_1+M_2+.....$converges then $f_1+f_2+....$converges uniformly.
How can I interpret what it means actually i.e. I want to visualize this theorem.Is there any way to visualize this theorem?

Comment: Think of it as bounding above a sequence of functions by a summable sequence.

Comment: what do you mean,please state more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s one visualisation (See the statement of [Weierstrass M test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)):

- Put $S_n = 2\sum_{k=1}^n M_k$, $S = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} M_k$, and draw the lines $y = S_n$ for each $n$. (Think of a [rainbow cake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_cookie) of finite thickness $S$ but infinitely many layers.)
- Let the *$n$th layer* be the plane between the lines $y=S_{n-1}$ and $y=S_n$. Put $Z_n = S_n - M_n$ for each $n$ and draw a dotted line $y=Z_n$ for each $n$. (The idea is that for each $n$ we can shift the $x$-axis to the $n$th dotted line, and the $n$th layer represents ‘$0 \pm M_n$’.)
- If for all $n$, you can plot $y=|f_n(x)|+Z_n$ within the $n$th layer then the M test is passed: you can add all of the $f_n$ together and the sum will converge.

Uniform convergence is (*I think*) guaranteed because the layers are the same thickness across the entire domain. For pointwise convergence, the layer thicknesses could vary with $x$, and so you would need to accumulate more layers (increase $n$) to guarantee that the total thickness is under control.

Comment: This question is answered by someone else in my profile so I thought that sharing it will help.